# How to color whole RichTextBox line with grey (not just text height)?

Tags: c#, wpf, richtextbox

I want to have grid-like appearance of `RichTextBox` - one paragraph is light-grey, then white, and so on... This code:

```
Paragraph pargrph = new Paragraph();
pargrph.Background = Brushes.LightGray;
this.richTextBox.Document.Blocks.Add(pargrph);
```

greys only the text height, not entire line height:

[image: measurement-demonstration]

How to color whole line with grey ?

Comment: Don't really understand the question but [does this help](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.richtextbox.selectionbackcolor.aspx)

Comment: @RedSerpent: thnx, but this is about text selection. For instance if I wanted to make red and blue grid (one line red, next blue, next red, etc...), I still had white color between two lines (I wanted to have only blue and red, no white between them)

Comment: @Tal if you set the Border you will see TextHeight == ParagraphHeight

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to change margin and / or padding:

```
pargrph.Margin = new Thickness(0);
pargrph.Padding = new Thickness(0);
```

Please also see this [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.documents.block.margin.aspx) article.